# Swift - Get 10's place of a decimal number

Tags: swift

How can I get 10's place of a decimal number in Swift?

Ex:

- 1.20 -> 10
- 1.90 -> 10
- 5.50 -> 10
- 20.30 -> 30
- 25.50 -> 30
- 29.00 -> 30
- 90.0 -> 90
- 90.1 -> 100
- 95.50 -> 100
- 99.01 -> 100
- 120.0 -> 120
- 121.1 -> 130
- 129.5 -> 130

Comment: So you want to round up to nearest 10?

Comment: Yes, nearest 10th multiplication number. @Sweeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically `ceil` operation, you just have to move the decimal point (divide by 10 and then multiply by 10):

```
func ceilTo10(_ value: Double) -> Int {
    return Int(ceil(value / 10) * 10)
}

print(ceilTo10(1.20)) // 10
print(ceilTo10(90.0)) // 90
print(ceilTo10(121.1)) // 130
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rounded(.up)`. Here's a helpful extension:

```
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {
    func roundedUpNearest10() -> Self {
        return (self / 10).rounded(.up) * 10
    }
}

for num in [ 1.2, 1.9, 5.5, 20.3, 25.5, 29, 90, 90.1, 95.5, 99.01, 120, 121.1, 129.5 ] {
    print(num, num.roundedUpNearest10())
}
```

Output:

> 1.2 10.0
>   1.9 10.0
>   5.5 10.0
>   20.3 30.0
>   25.5 30.0
>   29.0 30.0
>   90.0 90.0
>   90.1 100.0
>   95.5 100.0
>   99.01 100.0
>   120.0 120.0
>   121.1 130.0
>   129.5 130.0

If you actually want an `Int` result, update the extension:

```
extension BinaryFloatingPoint {
    func roundedUpNearest10() -> Int {
        return Int((self / 10).rounded(.up) * 10)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `ceil`  with this formula  `10` is nearest 10

Example:

```
    print(10 * Int(ceil(95.50 / 10)))
    print(10 * Int(ceil(99.1 / 10)))
    print(10 * Int(ceil(99.01 / 10)))
    print(10 * Int(ceil(129.5 / 10)))
    print(10 * Int(ceil(121.1 / 10)))
```